# Credit Union taking 2 months to post transactions

Tags: united-states, transaction, credit-unions

Is there a rule or law on how long credit unions can take to post transactions? Everything I've seen says it should take immediately as debit or 1 to 2 days as credit. However, I'm having some ATM withdrawals, checks and in store purchases taking up to 2 months to post/deduct. Completely random where one transaction from the same store will post immediately but another will take 2 months. If I use my bank debit card or a credit card, I have no issues. It's just this CU's debit card. My sister-in-law banks there too and spoke with them - all they said is it's the consumers responsibility to make sure the funds post. Which I get, but 2 months seems way out of the norm. Just wondering what their responsibility is for posting in a timely manner.

Comment: Whatever the answer, it's time for you to #1 keep detailed track of your spending on that account (in the old days it would mean writing everything in the check register), and #2 find another bank/CU for your checking account.

Answer (score 3):

Two months for posting of the ATM transactions is way too long. I would complain, then look for another institution.

Some of the timing of the posting the checks, debit card transactions, or credit card transactions are not the fault of your bank/credit Union. They depend on the network involved, and the speed that the store or other person pushes the transaction forward.

I have seen debit card and credit card transactions appear as a hold within minutes, but still take 2 or three days to be replaced by the actual transaction. The idea that debit card transactions is instantaneous is a myth. But if an electronic transaction goes beyond that then something is wrong. Paper transactions will always take longer.

> Just wondering what their responsibility is for posting in a timely
>   manner.

Just from their business model, a bank or credit union should want to pull money from a customers account as soon as possible. The terms of their network, and the rules of the banking system would require them to transfer the funds from their institution as quickly as possible. Once they do that they will want to reduce your balance to make their books balance. They have no reason to not pull the funds from your account. That makes me wonder if they are always doing this slowly, they are having other issues.

I would look for another Credit Union. The definitions about what it takes to be a member of a CU have broadened and many people qualify for more than one.